# Assigning values to NSUInteger using the | (OR) operator?

Tags: objective-c, integer, bit-manipulation

I'm reading Apple's documentation on NSDate. In one of their code examples I see something I haven't seen before:
[doc link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW3). Here's the example code.

```
NSDate *startDate = ...;
NSDate *endDate = ...;

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                 initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                          fromDate:startDate
                                          toDate:endDate options:0];
NSInteger months = [components month];
NSInteger days = [components day];
```

I'm really confused by the use of the (OR) | operator when assigning value(s) to unitFlags. Can someone tell me what's happening there? Do they both get assigned or does it check on first, and if nil looks for the other? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the OR operator (||). That's the bitwise-OR operator, and may be the problem with your understanding.

If you have a look at the definition for the enums you used, you'll see they are defined for compatibility and the base enum is `CFCalendarUnit`.
So let's have a look at a snippet the definition for `CFCalendarUnit`

```
kCFCalendarUnitEra = (1UL << 1),
kCFCalendarUnitYear = (1UL << 2),
kCFCalendarUnitMonth = (1UL << 3),
kCFCalendarUnitDay = (1UL << 4),
```

Have a look at the values that the enums have been assigned to:

```
kCFCalendarUnitEra = 1 leftShifted once = 2            = 00010
kCFCalendarUnitYear = 1 leftShifted twice = 4          = 00100
kCFCalendarUnitMonth = 1 leftShifted three times = 8   = 01000
kCFCalendarUnitDay = 1 leftShifted four times = 16     = 10000
```

Notice that each of the results in binary has only one (1) in it.

Using the bitwise-OR operator:

```
NSUInteger unitFlags = (NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)
unitFlags = 01000 (bitwise-OR) 10000
```

"Bitwise" means take each bit and perform the operation, in this case OR

```
01000 |
10000 
=====
11000
```

---

You then pass this value to your calendar, where it will decode the information using a command like the following:

```
if (unitFlags & kCFCalendarUnitMonth == kCFCalendarUnitMonth) //Where & is the bitwise-AND operator

11000 &    //Unit Flags
01000      //Value of Month
=====
01000      //If unit flags contains month flag, month flag is returned.
```

---

Using this technique. You can store 32 boolean pieces of information in a single 32-bit int by "flagging" each of the bits and quickly compound and retrieve information. This avoids methods like:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian 
                                      hasEraUnit:NO
                                      hasYearUnit:NO
                                      hasMonthUnit:YES
                                      hasDayUnit:YES
                                      hasHourUnit:NO
                                      ....
                                      hasYearForWeekOfYearUnit:NO
                                      fromDate:startDate
                                      toDate:endDate options:0];
```

Comment: Fantastic detailed explanation! Awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They use this number as a flag. Basically, the receiver is going to look for which bits are 1 on the flag. For example, let's say you use the first 4 bits of an integer as a flag, you would look to see which ones of those numbers are 1 and which ones are zero to know which elements of the flags are activated. This allows you to use the same variable to pass more than one piece of information efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd still like to know how this works in the particular example shown. On a functional level, I just drop in two integers into a single variable (using |) and out they pop again when I call on it later? If I understand that correctly, do they come out in the order they were put in and what are the limitations? Can I assign three variables?

Comment: you can use this kind of operations, for example, to save the months of the year where an event is repeating. you can say that the LSB is the first month of the year, so, if you have number 1 (000000000001 base 2) means that only january is active. if you have 17 (000000010001 base 2), means that you have january and may. If you see this, you realize that you can pass a lot of information (depending on the context) using bit flags.